# Simplest way to empty a database with ForeignKeys without deleting/creating it

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to empty a Mysql database (eg destroy all tables) . But: I don't have the permission to delete that database. So I can't use the trick

```
DELETE DATABASE x; 
CREATE DATABASE x;
```

Is they an automated way to remove all the tables (given that they are a lot of foreign keys to remove before having the actual right to remove one table) ?

Someone must have written an automated script for that, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off foreign keys check and delete all tables. 
Add before droping.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE `table1`, `table2` ... ;
```